How to overide metrocombox style triggers?
I am using MetroCombobox. When the control is disabled, the text inside the combo is having a different light foregroundcolor.This makes it not readable.I was asked to increase brightness of the disabled control so that users can read the test inside. So i tried to add a style in my xaml as below.But now, the original style of the combobox is also lost. Wht is it that i am doing wrong? It now looks like a normal combo box, with box type look, with all 4 borders around it. I know this below style is working, but it has overwritten the original style
 <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroComboBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
`

Normal Combo Box - 
Expected Combo Box - 
